# Create CSV file with data from my model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, export-to-csv, ruby-csv

I have a user model with name and id.

I want to store the of all the columns in users to a csv file.

How do I use CSV.generate function to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following code will write the attributes of all users to a file:

```
CSV.open("path/to/file.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << User.attribute_names
  User.all.each do |user|
    csv << user.attributes.values
  end
end
```

Source: [How to convert array of ActiveRecord models to CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200734/how-to-convert-array-of-activerecord-models-to-csv) (duplicate question)